# Translating triangles with OpenGL and uC++

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm struggling with a triangle translation in OpenGL and using uC++. Every bird (triangle) is a thread. The thing is that when the birds are translating, the camera or general image is moving up or down.

The draw code is this one:

```
   void Graphics::draw(){
       double AxisX;
       double AxisY;
       double Direction;

       for (int i = 0; i < numBirds; i++)
       {
           AxisX     = birds[i]->Px;
           AxisY      = birds[i]->Py;
           Direction = birds[i]->Dir - 90;

           glColor3d(1, 1, 1);

       //Operacion para el triangulo
           glTranslated(AxisX, AxisY, 0.0f);
           glRotated(Direction, 0, 0, 1);


           /*
               Se mantienen estas proporciones:
                Base: 1
                Altura: 1.9364916731
                Lado (isosceles): 2
          */
           glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); // Inicio del dibujo
           glVertex3d(-5, 0, 0); // Primer vertice
           glVertex3d( 5, 0, 0); // Segundo vertice
           glVertex3d( 0, 15, 0); // Tercer vertice
           glEnd(); // Fin del dibujo

          // Deshago las operaciones de rotacion y translacion
           glRotated(-Direction, 0, 0, 1);
           glTranslated(-AxisX, -AxisY, 0.0f);
       }
   }
```

The question is, how can I fix this? I've been struggling for hours getting nothing.

Comment: Have you tried pushing the gl states at the start, then popping them when finished?

Comment: What does `Every bird (triangle) is a thread. ` even mean?

Comment: Nathan, I did that and now is working, thank you!

And derhass, when you are working with uC++ your class it's a thread or task similar that when you use pthread, but it's object oriented. So I have the task bird, and every bird constructed is a thread.